# How to compute the utility function when risk aversion is equal to 1?

Tags: utility

How to compute the utility function when risk aversion is equal to 1?
If the utility function of consumption is set as,

$\frac{C^{1-\sigma} - 1}{1-\sigma}$.
Is it meaningful as $\sigma$ is equal to 1?
How to prove it if so? Thanks a lot!

Comment: absolute or relative risk aversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the limit as $\sigma \rightarrow 1$,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 1} \frac{C^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}.
\end{align*}
This will then results in log utility. Calculating the limit goes as follows.
Since plugging in $\sigma = 0$ would give $\frac 0 0$, we use L'Hopital's rule.
This gives us
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 1} \frac{C^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}
  &= \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 1} \frac{- C^{1-\sigma} \log C}{-1} \\
  &= \log C.
\end{align*}